# kafka connect mongo on kafka MSK

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, amazon-msk

I am using Kafka MSK in AWS. So we don't have native kafka connect with all required connectors like on confluent. 
Actually I work with kakfa mongo connector and I want to find a way to push the kafka mongo connector jar to an on an instance of kafka MSK cluster. 
The path to which the jar will be pushed is the plugins.path as defined in the properties of the used connector.

ANy way to make it please ?

Comment: Kafka Connect should be deployed externally to the brokers, in any environment

Answer (score 4):

MSK doesn't give you a hosted Kafka Connect worker. You'd need to provision and run this yourself, e.g. on EC2. This work would then connect to your Kafka cluster (MSK in this case)

To be clear: MSK is only the hosted Kafka brokers (and Zookeeper). It does not include Kafka Connect, which is what you need in order to run connectors.

Comment: I'm not even sure you can SSH into MSK

Comment: but my understanding is that the connect worker shall run on an instance of MSK cluster , so the jar should not be to EC2 no ?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect (unless you have a reference you can share showing otherwise?). You cannot run Kafka Connect on MSK itself, you need to provision and run it yourself